# Where is the icon in the source code window for "continue to current line" in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode

In XCode, before version 5, if you were in the source code windows debugging, you could place the cursor on the left side of the window just by where you enable/disable breakpoints and a small "Continue to current line" icon would appear.

If you clicked it, execution would advance to that line.

Now that I've upgraded to Xcode 5, it doesn't seem to be there anymore.

Has it been removed or is there another way (beside going to the Debug menu or doing a keyboard shortcut) to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. If you right-click just to the right of the line number you want to execute to, a small menu appears that includes the option to 'Continue to here'. Apparently the little icon is no more.